# How to assign specific title to each line in the data file in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, draw, geometry

I have a data file which keeps all the x, y coordinates and radius values for drawing circles. Each circle stand for a region. Up to now I drew the circles. But I want to assign specific legend to each line in the data file. Because after drawing regions, I want to put some points on this regions depend on the region number. However I couldn't figure out how to do it. Is there anyone who know how to assign a specific legend to the circles depend on its line number in the data file. The data file looks like

> X Y R Legend
>
> 5 6 0.1 1
>
> ....

and so on. I want to use the last column as title to assign to the circles. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how exactly you want to show the corresponding "title". Let's assume that the data file `circles.dat` contains following data:

```
5 6.0 0.1 1
5 5.5 0.1 2
4 5.0 0.2 3
```

One option would be to plot the circles and use the fourth column as labels which are placed at the centers of the individual circles. This can be directly achieved with the `with labels` plotting style as:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'fig1.png'

fName = 'circles.dat'

unset key

set xr [3:6]
set yr [4:7]

set size square
set tics out nomirror
set xtics 3,1,6
set mxtics 2
set ytics 4,1,7
set mytics 2

plot \
    fName u 1:2:3 w circles lc rgb 'red' lw 2, \
    '' u 1:2:4 w labels tc rgb 'blue'
```

This produces:
[image]

Alternatively, one might want to put those labels into the legend of the graph. Perhaps there is a more elegant solution, nevertheless one way is to
plot each line of the data file separately and extract the fourth column (to be used as key title) manually:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'fig2.png'

fName = 'circles.dat'

unset key

set xr [3:6]
set yr [4:7]

set size square
set tics out nomirror
set xtics 3,1,6
set mxtics 2
set ytics 4,1,7
set mytics 2

set key top right reverse

stat fName nooutput

plot \
    for [i=0:STATS_records-1] fName u 1:2:3 every ::i::i w circles t system(sprintf("awk 'NR==%d{print $4}' '%s'", i+1, fName))
```

This gives:
[image]